# Multiple click in list row

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListView` in Android. Each listitem has 2 textviews. If I click one `TextView` I want to open an `Activity` and if I click another one I want to do another thing.

My adapter´s code is lil this:

```
public class LazyAdapterHelpCentersAlava extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    HashMap<String, String> song;
    Typeface tf; 

    Context context;

    public LazyAdapterHelpCentersAlava(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, String font) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), font);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_help_centers, null);

        //TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.id); // title
        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nombre); // title
        TextView localizacion = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.localizacion);
        TextView email = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.email);
        TextView web = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.web);

        song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(Help.TAG_NOMBRE));
        web.setText(song.get(Help.TAG_TELEFONO));
        localizacion.setText(song.get(Help.TAG_DIRECCION));
        email.setText(song.get(Help.TAG_EMAIL));

        title.setTypeface(tf);
        web.setTypeface(tf);
        localizacion.setTypeface(tf);
        email.setTypeface(tf);

        web = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Need to start an Activity here     
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }
}
```

I have put click listener on `web` but, I don´t know how to open an Activity, because it says error like this **The method `startActivity(Intent)` is undefined for the type new `View.OnClickListener(){}`**

Can somebody help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to call startActivity on Context. In your case you have it as activity. Call activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Can you use my code please? thanks

Comment: In the onClick where you need to start the activity. Type activity.startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use context of adapter

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null){
            context = parent.getContext();
         //other code
        }
```

then

```
        web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent redirect = new Intent(context,New.class);
               context.startActivity(redirect);  
                }
           });
```

Comment: I get an error in this line "Intent redirect = new Intent(context,New.class);"

Comment: replace your class name instead of newclass

Answer (score 0):

Try this because you are giving context in constructor as Activity a

```
      web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent redirect = new Intent(activity,New.class);
           activity.startActivity(redirect);  
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Adapter is a nested class inside your `MainActivity` then you need to do something like this.

```
web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);  
    }
});
```

And if your adapter is not a nested class inside your `MainActivity` you need to pass the `Context` of your `Activity` to that `LazyAdapterHelpCentersAlava` first and then start an `Activity` using the `Context`.

```
public class LazyAdapterHelpCentersAlava extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    HashMap<String, String> song;
    Typeface tf; 

    Context context;

    public LazyAdapterHelpCentersAlava(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, String font) {
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), font);
        context = ctx;   // Initialize the context here. 
    }

    // .. Here are the other functions ... Omitted for clarity

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_help_centers, null);

        // Here are the other lines in getView function. Omitted for clarity

        web = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Need to start an Activity here   
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(newActivity); 
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in oncreate() method

```
this.context=this;
```

Add this line under web Onclick Method

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,NextActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

NextActivity is the Activity where you have to go

Answer (score 0):

use context,

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick() method, add this:

```
 Intent startActivity=new Intent("abc.Xyz");
    startActivity(newActivity);
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml, add:

```
<activity android:name=".Xyz"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="abc.XYZ" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Note: In the above code **Xyz** is the ClassName of the activity you want to start and **abc** is the PackageName in which the Activity file is present.